# Get average salary for department (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 3 tables Employyes, Department and Salary

Here is Department Model:

```
public partial class Department
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Department()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Parent_Id { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Employee model:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Salaries = new HashSet<Salary>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Department_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Salary> Salaries { get; set; }
}
```

And here is Salary model:

```
 public partial class Salary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Employee_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get Average Salary for every department

So I created ViewModel for it

```
 public class SalariesViewModel
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageSalary { get; set; }
}
```

And try to write this method

```
**public List<SalariesViewModel> GetAverageSalary() {

        var massagedEmployees = db.Employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department)
                              .Select(g =>
                                new {
                                    Department = g.Key,
                                    SalaryAvg = g.Average(x => x.Salaries)
                                });
    }**
```

But I cannot set `x.Salaries.Amount`.

How I can calculate average salary per department?

**Update**

Here is sample inputs for Department , Employees and Salary

**Salary inputs**

[image]

**Employyes input**

[image]

**Departments input**

[image]

So at output I need to have smth like this It Department - 200$

Comment: `Salaries` is a collection, so you would need a `.SelectMany()`, but surely you want the average of the most recent salary for each employee?

Comment: I think @Stephen means that your table structure makes it seem like you have records of old employee salaries which, if not filtered, will contaminate your average.

Comment: Yes I know you want it for a department ). Each employee has multiple salaries - do you really want to include all x salaries for Jo Blogs, including what their salary was 20 years ago in your calculations

Comment: So if department A contains only one employee named Joe, and 20 years ago his salary was $20K, and his current salary is 100K, you expect the result for that department to be $60K? Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Okay. I will update post now@mjwills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need the average of the current salary for the employees, break this into 2 queries

First generate an object containing the employees current salary

```
var employees = db.Employees.Select(x => new
{
    Department = x.Department.Name,
    Name = x.Name,
    Salary = x.Salaries.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).First().Amount
});
```

Note this assumes that an employee will contain at least one salary

Next group these objects by `Department`

```
var data = employees.GroupBy(m => m.Department).Select(x => new SalariesViewModel
{
    DepartmentName = x.Key,
    AverageSalary = x.Average(y => y.Salary)
}).ToList();
return data;
```

Comment: Get this error

`The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null`

Comment: I did say that that it assumed that each employee has at least one salary :) I assume you must have some records that are missing

Comment: Ah, Yes , that's is

Comment: It depends what could be `null` as to how best fix this. But it really makes no sense that the `Date`, `Amount` and `EmployeeId` properties of you `Salary` class are nullable, and I would suggest that is what you should be fixing rather that testing for data that is wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As many have explained in the comments, you may be looking for the average salary based on the latest month. In such a case you could get this by

```
Employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department.Name)
                          .Select(g =>
                            new {
                                Department = g.Key,
                                SalaryAvg = g.Average(x => x.Salaries.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date).FirstOrDefault().Amount)
                            });
```

If you insist on getting it for all the values available against an employee (which I doubt), you could do this

```
Employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department.Name)
                          .Select(g =>
                            new {
                                Department = g.Key,
                                SalaryAvg = g.Average(x => x.Salaries.Average(s => s.Amount))
                            });
```

Note: Nulls are not being handled in the above queries.